# What's the best way to redis-cli psubscribe and pipe to grep

Tags: redis, grep, sh, redis-cli

What is a good way to psubscribe on a redis pattern and pipe to grep.

I tried

```
redis-cli psubscribe "somepattern*" | grep somevalue
```

But it seems to not work if the pattern doesn't publish frequently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving filtered redis-cli output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691811/saving-filtered-redis-cli-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

[How to redirect the output of redis subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922809/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-redis-subscription)

```
stdbuf -oL redis-cli psubscribe "*"  | grep --line-buffered sometext
```