# Saving filtered redis-cli output to a file

Tags: bash, redis, output, monitoring, redis-cli

I am trying to find when and how the cache is flushed, planned to use the command `redis-cli monitor | grep -iE "del|flush" > redis_log.txt` for that, but for some reason the file is empty. If i use the command without `> redis_log.txt` part - it shows a correct output in the terminal, if i use `redis-cli monitor > redis_log.txt` command - it also saves an actual output to the file, but together it fails, only an empty file is created. Has anybody met a similar issue before?

Comment: Try `redis-cli ... > redis_log.txt 2>&1` , also there might be an issue about buffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue you notice certainly comes from the I/O buffering applied to the `grep` command, especially when its standard output is not attached to a terminal, but redirected to a file or so.

To be more precise, see e.g. [this nice blog article](https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/grep-and-output-buffering/) which concludes with this wrap-up:

> Here’s how buffering is usually set up:
>
> - STDIN is always buffered.
> - STDERR is never buffered.
> - if STDOUT is a terminal, line buffering will be automatically selected. Otherwise, block buffering (probably 4096 bytes) will be used.
>
> […] these 3 points explain all “weird” behaviors.

#### General solution

To tweak the I/O streams buffering of a program, a very handy program provided by coreutils is [`stdbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html).

So for your use case:

- you may want to replace `grep -iE "del|flush"` with:
  `stdbuf -o0 grep -iE "del|flush"` to completely disable STDOUT buffering;
- or if you'd like some trade-off and just have STDOUT line-buffering,
  you may want to replace `grep -iE "del|flush"` with:

  - either `stdbuf -oL grep -iE "del|flush"`,
  - or `grep --line-buffered -iE "del|flush"`.

#### Wrap-up

Finally as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691811/saving-filtered-redis-cli-output-to-a-file/69692606#comment123186200_69691811) by [@jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel), you'll probably want to redirect STDERR as well to your log file in order not to miss some errors messages… Hence, for example:

```sh
redis-cli monitor | stdbuf -o0 grep -iE "del|flush" > redis_log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Adding "--line-buffered" did the thing, thanks.